# Strike Force 7 (for Runequest!?!) How about BRP?

Tags: runequest, basic-role-playing

I just discovered that there is a Runequest version of *Strike Force 7*! I've often seen Strike Force 7 for Spycraft or Savage Worlds and while I love the idea for that setting, I don't care for those systems enough to purchase it. My question is while I don't have Mongoose Runequest, I do have BRP gold book and the Chaosium RuneQuest3. Would those systems be close enough to use said Strike Force 7 without too much or any hassle?

(I guess this is a question about RQ3's compatibility with MRQ and/or any input on the Runequest version of Strike Force 7).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The BRP gold book is a good general start, and will provide the core of what you need, I personally find the percentile approach nice and easy to change to what I need across the various games.

Personally I'm not a fan of Strike Force 7 and it's overt caricature, but from my little experience of the supplement it provides plenty of content if that's what you're after. In terms of a more modern outlook that you can have a similar GI-Joe style adventure the [Modern Equipment Catalog](http://catalog.chaosium.com/product_info.php?products_id=5059) will be compatible with BRP and I think provide a much richer toolkit than Strike Force 7; seeming as you can take the equipment elsewhere.

If you are looking for a modern BRP-ish experience please look up [A|State](http://www.contestedground.co.uk/astint.html) for a more Dark City tone, or for a more Sci-Fi bent even look into Fantasy Flight Games [Warhammer 40k trilogy](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_colecciones.asp?eidc=2) (Dark Heresy, Rogue Trader & Deathwatch) which is again percentile based.